# How to style groups of data as they are loaded incrementally in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In WinRT if we want to support incremental loading, the data source must implement the [ISupportIncrementalLoading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701916) interface. I have this implemented and the data displays correctly in a GridView.

The data I'm incrementally pulling down has a date associated with it. I want to display the associated month as a "Group Header" for the data already pulled down. However, I don't see a clean way to style in the "Group Header" as the months of the incrementally loaded items change.

[image: Group Headers inserted into incrementally loaded data.]

I realize that normal grouping in WinRT is supported via the [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR209833), however as far as I understand this is incompatible with ISupportIncrementalLoading. Which makes sense for the general case since newly loaded items may not actually be placed at the end. However, in this case I know the data is already grouped by months on the server and pulled down in order.

Is there a way to style in the "Group Header" as I drew above?

Comment: I've found a blog(http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-gridview-performance-problems-on-windows-rt-tablets/) that partially deals with the problem, by making the group header part of the elements and then styling it differently. Is there any way to style it closer to what normal grouping looks like?

Answer (score 1):

CollectionViewSource does compatible with ISupportIncrementalLoading, just set the source of CollectionViewSource to a something implements ISupportIncrementalLoading.

Comment: Have you tried this? Doing so does not trigger the LoadMoreItemsAsync() nor HasMoreItems() overrides to be called.

Comment: sorry I did not notice you mentioned you enabled grouping. Grouping does not work with UI virtualization. MSFT enforce every UIElement in ItemsControl to be same size to get UI virtualization. It's a big assumption for them to develop winRT faster.